# What is the meaning of "where not"?

Tags: sentence-construction

I read a sentence in Merriam Webster dictionaries which was:

> The misery was general, **where not** glossed over by liberal application of alcohol.

Does "where not" here mean somewhat like "not a place where it was not"?
I was confused because I have never seen this sort of grammatical construction before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means, essentially, "except where".

> The misery was general, **where not** glossed over by liberal application of alcohol.

This could also be written as:

> The misery was general, **except where it was** glossed over by a liberal application of alcohol.

Basically, everyone was miserable, except the people who were drunk.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is a bit figurative. It can also be interpreted as

> **The misery(a state or feeling of great physical or mental distress or discomfort) was general where it was not glossed over(to avoid considering sth) by liberal application of alcohol.**

Here where is used as a relative pronoun and **it was** is omitted. And this is a correct gramatical construction.